# JASidePanel iOS: Style Left Button on navbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

so I've been trying to style the left bar button on the navbar. 
Mainly the button style I wan't un-styled (the same kinda style as a UIButton style set to custom).

Does anyone know how? 
Thank you,
James

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look at this function in JASidePanelController.m

```
+ (UIImage *)defaultImage {
    static UIImage *defaultImage = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(20.f, 13.f), NO, 0.0f);

        [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 1)] fill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 5, 20, 1)] fill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 20, 1)] fill];

        [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 1, 20, 2)] fill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 6,  20, 2)] fill];
        [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 11, 20, 2)] fill];   

        defaultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    });
    return defaultImage;
}
```

This is the part that makes the 3 lines on the customButton.

It is being called by this:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)leftButtonForCenterPanel {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[[self class] defaultImage] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(toggleLeftPanel:)];
}
```

So making it custom is by for example:

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)leftButtonForCenterPanel {
UIImage *faceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
UIButton *face = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
face.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, faceImage.size.width, faceImage.size.height );
[face setImage:faceImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[face addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(toggleLeftPanel:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:face];
}
```

Please change it to your situation. Hope this helps...